# Android linking Faild

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

ERROR:C:\Users\aron.kibet\AndroidStudioProjects\Status_Saver22\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:2: AAPT: error: attribute layout_height (aka com.example.status_saver22:layout_height) not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your respected View of the xml file.

Happy Coding :)